# how to resolve problem of batch normalisation syntax error from following keras code?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I have implemented a CNN code referring to AlexNet architecture (https://www.mydatahack.com/building-alexnet-with-keras/) through keras lib in python, but I am getting an error as: model.add(BatchNormalization()) syntax error. The architecture given in the image file, I am trying to implement. [CNN architecture and table description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PT2Uq.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PT2Uq.png)

the following python code I am using:

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, load_img, img_to_array
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization


batch_size = 4
num_classes = 123
epochs = 80

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=96, input_shape=(88, 128, 1), kernel_size=(18, 18), strides=1, activation='relu', padding='valid'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2)
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(45, 45), strides=1, activation='relu', padding='valid'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=2)
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(1024))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
```

how do i resolve this problem?

Comment: Can you paste the full error?

Comment: File "GEINet.py", line 19
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: please refer AlexNet link code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `)` at the end of both of your `MaxPooling2D` lines. Change each `strides=2)` to `strides=2))`.

Comment: ok, thanks now i am getting following error:   ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 45 from 35 for 'conv2d_2/convolution' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,35,55,96], [45,45,96,256].

Comment: @sanjaygupta Kernel size is _way_ too big. Most people nowadays use 3x3. Look up how convolutional kernels work if you don't understand them.

Comment: that will be resolve if i increase input size of image but input size given in following paper as 88x128 (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7550060)

Comment: thank you very much it is resolved when I swap the dimensions from (88,128,1) to (128,88,1)